# Add text over another text

Tags: html, css

I want to add text over another text. Like if I have a letter 'A' then there will be two 'A' letters overlapping each other.

Here is my code-

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
height: 100%;
}

.container {
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: black;
}

span.element {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 45px;
color: #fff;
margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <span class="element">A</span>
        <span class="element">B</span>
        <span class="element">C</span>
        <span class="element">D</span>
        <span class="element">E</span>
        <span class="element">F</span>
        <span class="element">G</span>
        <span class="element">H</span>
    </div>
```

How to add text over text? I tried to create a `span` with two child spans with `position:absolute` but the spans are coming at top left not in between the container.

Comment: have you tried text-shadow?

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/nakata/pen/gveKba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `position: absolute;`, as you wrote. But it's important that

1.) the overlapping element is a child element of the overlapped element (see below - I nested an "A" span inside the first of your spans) and

2.) the parent element has to have `position: relative;` to serve as the position reference point for the absolutely positioned element.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

span.element {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.x1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  font-size: 38px;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="element">A<span class="x1">A</span></span>

  <span class="element">B</span>
  <span class="element">C</span>
  <span class="element">D</span>
  <span class="element">E</span>
  <span class="element">F</span>
  <span class="element">G</span>
  <span class="element">H</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your requirements?

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
height: 100%;
}

.container {
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: black;
}

span.element {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 45px;
color: #fff;
margin: 0 5px;
text-shadow: 5px 5px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <span class="element">A</span>
        <span class="element">B</span>
        <span class="element">C</span>
        <span class="element">D</span>
        <span class="element">E</span>
        <span class="element">F</span>
        <span class="element">G</span>
        <span class="element">H</span>
    </div>
```

With the `text-shadow` property, you can achieve an shadow / overlapping effect. The less `px` you assign to the property, the more it will overlap, but also be less visible:

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
height: 100%;
}

.container {
height: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: black;
}

span.element {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 45px;
color: #fff;
margin: 0 5px;
text-shadow: 2px 2px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <span class="element">A</span>
        <span class="element">B</span>
        <span class="element">C</span>
        <span class="element">D</span>
        <span class="element">E</span>
        <span class="element">F</span>
        <span class="element">G</span>
        <span class="element">H</span>
    </div>
```